# O documento principal do estilo das folhas de estilo definidas nas Importações HTML é obsoleto?

Tags: html5

Estou percebendo que todos os sites estão recebendo essa mensagem no *console*:

> *[Deprecation] Styling master document from stylesheets defined in HTML
> Imports is deprecated, and is planned to be removed in M65, around
> March 2018. Please refer to the [link](https://github.com/TakayoshiKochi/deprecate-style-in-html-imports) for possible
> migration paths.*

---

> [Obsoleto] O documento principal do estilo das folhas de estilo
> definidas nas Importações HTML é obsoleto e está planejado para ser
> removido em M65, em torno de março de 2018. Por favor, consulte o
> [link](https://github.com/TakayoshiKochi/deprecate-style-in-html-imports) para possíveis caminhos de migração.

O que seria isso?

Comment: https://github.com/TakayoshiKochi/deprecate-style-in-html-imports